# Running Javascript "getValue" twice for optional (hidden forums)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, if-statement

I have a few forms that I need to be hidden until a user clicks an option. I am sadly a total newbie with Javascript. I found this code on SO, and it works great for 1 field, but when I try to do multiple, it breaks the fields (only one works).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getValue(x) {
if(x.value == 'custom'){
document.getElementById("yourfield").style.display = 'block';
 }
 else{

document.getElementById("yourfield").style.display = 'none';
}
}
</script>
```

I tried changing the fields and the value (and adding the 2 scripts on top of each other). But one of the fields will not show.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getValue(x) {
if(x.value == 'othercustom'){
document.getElementById("otherfield").style.display = 'block';
 }
 else{

document.getElementById("otherfield").style.display = 'none';
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Could you post your HTML code, my friend?

Comment: I'm dumb, I just figured it out. It took me looking at the code in SO to figure out what I did wrong. You simply have to put the other "if statement" inside the function, instead of using 2 functions.

Comment: Well played, my friend :d

Comment: Hmm... but now I cannot open both text inputs at once like this... Only one at a time..

Comment: Fixed again, just re-named the function and made 2 functions now. Turns out JS a lot like PHP in these situations.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getValue(x) {
if(x.value == 'othercustom'){
document.getElementById("otherfield").style.display = 'block';
for changes
}
else{

document.getElementById("otherfield").style.display = 'none';
changes
 }
 }

function getOther(x) {
 if(x.value == 'custom'){
 document.getElementById("yourfield").style.display = 'block';
 identifier for changes
 }
 else{

 document.getElementById("yourfield").style.display = 'none';
 for changes
 }
  }
 </script>
```